# SSL android certificate issue

Tags: android

I am using Socket in android with https so I need to make the connection secure. So for that I am using this certificate-

```
  private final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts= new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
    }
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                   String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }
} };
```

Now all is working well and the connection is also established, but I am not understanding or I don't know if using this type of certificate is secure or not?

Should I use this or not?

Comment: this type of implementation is secure because certificate is used to estabish connection but if you need more security you may use X509Extension class

Comment: but i think this certificate trusted for all type so is this secure or not? and second one is  if i put certificate file in raw folder and use from there is this much better or not?

Comment: The certificate may be valid but it also may be from an attacker. One answer is to pin the certificate, that is to verify that the certificate is from the source you expect to connect to. Note: over 1,500 Let's Encrypt certificates have been issued with some form on "pay pal" in the name.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is **vulnerable** to a [Man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack!

You are using https, so the data is encrypted while being transmitted, which is good. But there is no check that the other side is who you expect it to be, which is bad.

The above custom `TrustManager` does not make any checks and implicitly trusts everything. In the code it is even called `trustAllCerts`, which you explicitly do **not** want to do. You will want to check the certificate chain to see if it comes from a source that you trust.

The problem is that an attacker can intercept your https traffic by placing a proxy between you and your endpoint. The intercepting proxy can provide its own certificate and can thus decrypt the traffic and do whatever it wants with it. it can also set up an https connection with the endpoint and read the data it gets from there. Thus the attacker can read what you send, can read what you'll receive and can change what you send and will receive.

Comment: All true but no solution. One answer is to pin the certificate, that is to verify that the certificate is from the source you expect to connect to.